# How to create bordered text using PIL

Tags: python, text, colors, python-imaging-library

Is there a way to create text with PIL, but make the borders black and the inside of the text white? I tried overlaying two versions of the same text but with different colors, but they don't line up correctly.

Comment: Where is your code? Can you show us an example of what you want and what you're getting?

Comment: Just the other day I was looking at https://github.com/danieldiekmeier/memegenerator/blob/master/memegenerator.py#L41, which I believe does what you're looking for. First it draws the text repeatedly in the background color with various small spatial offsets, effectively making it "bleed" outwards slightly. Then it draws the foreground text on top of that once.